# Backing up Windows 2008 R2 to a network share from command line - hidden partition problem

Tags: backup, command-line-interface, windows-server-2008-r2

does anyone know how to backup Windows 2008 R2 with hidden partition to a network share? For Windows 2008 I used:

```
Wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Backup -include:C:,D: -vssFull -quiet
```

but now when Windows 2008 R2 has his hidden 100mb partition on first disk I don't know how to add it to "-include:C:,D:".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've found solution. Since GUID can be used in include then I used GUID of hidden 100mb partition.

```
Wbadmin start backup -backupTarget:\\xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx\Backup -include:\\?\Volume{7daf776e-64b8-11de-9959-806e6f6e6963}\,C:,D: -vssFull -quiet
```

Answer (score 2):

add the -allCritical switch to enable the bare metal restore

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not possible using the Windows backup program [wbadmin](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742083%28WS.10%29.aspx):

The `-include` switch:

> Specifies the comma-delimited list of
>   volume drive letters, volume mount
>   points, or GUID-based volume names to
>   include in the backup. This parameter
>   should be used only when -backupTarget
>   is specified.

If you want to make a backup of that partition you should consider doing a disk image backup using some third-party product like [Acronis TrueImage](http://www.acronis.com/enterprise/products/ATISWin/). Answers to this [question here on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/1514/what-is-your-recommended-disk-cloning-tool) mention other tools for creating disk images.